# Changing one appointment in a series in VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, calendar

How do I find a SERIES of APPOINTMENTS in My Outlook Calendar and how to change it?

I use the following code to find and change a single appointment/meeting.

```
Private Sub ChangeAppointment(SearchDate As String, SearchApptSubject As String)        

    'SearchDate = "7/12/2017"
    'SearchApptSubject = "Leave Office!"

    Dim oOL As New Outlook.Application
    Dim oNS As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim oAppointments As Object
    Dim oAppointmentItem As Outlook.AppointmentItem
    Dim ItemDate As String
    Dim strSubject As String, strBody As String

    Set oNS = oOL.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set oAppointments = oNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderCalendar)

    For Each oAppointmentItem In oAppointments.Items

        ItemDate = Format(oAppointmentItem.Start, "mm/dd/yy")
        ItemSubject = oAppointmentItem.Subject

        If SearchDate = ItemDate And SearchApptSubject = ItemSubject Then 'Check all events on current date.

            oAppointmentItem.Start = cdate("7/12/2017 6:00 PM")
            oAppointmentItem.END = cdate("7/12/2017 6:01 PM")
            oAppointmentItem.Subject = 'Time to go home!'                
            oAppointmentItem.Save  

            Exit For

        End If

    Next

End Sub
```

But when trying to find appointments that are part of a series the code won't find it. I would like to know how to find appointments in a series AND how to change just one appointment in that series. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you code that calls Sort does nothing - you call Sort on a temporary object (implicit variable created by the compiler) that you never use. 
Secondly, you need to set the `IncludeRecurrences` property, and ten restrict the collection (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-includerecurrences-property-outlook)

```
    dim oItems = oAppointments.Items
    oItems.Sort ("[Start]")
    oItems.Restrict("[Start] > '01-01-2017' AND ("[Start] < '01-07-2017'  ")
    For Each oAppointmentItem In oItems
      ...
```